# mb_detect_encoding doesn't properly working with Windows-1250 (CP1250)

Tags: php, encoding, cp1250

I have problem with detecting CP1250 in [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php), in my case I want detect 3 encodings:

```
mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8,ISO-8859-2,Windows-1250')
```

But Windows isn't in supported encodings, any solution?

Answer (score 7):

`mb_detect_encoding` *always* "detects" single-byte encodings. You can read about this in the documentation for [`mb_detect_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php):

> mbstring currently implements the following encoding detection
>   filters. If there is an invalid byte sequence for the following
>   encodings, encoding detection will fail.
>
> UTF-8, UTF-7, ASCII,
>   EUC-JP,SJIS, eucJP-win, SJIS-win, JIS, ISO-2022-JP
>
> For ISO-8859-X, mbstring always detects as ISO-8859-X.
>
> For UTF-16, UTF-32, UCS2 and UCS4, encoding detection will fail
>   always.

Conclusions:

1. It's meaningless to ask for detection of ISO-8859-2; it will always tell you "yes, that's it" (unless of course it detects UTF-8 first).
2. Windows-1250 is not supported, but even if it were it would work exactly like ISO-8859-2.

In general, it is impossible to detect single-byte encodings with accuracy. If you find yourself needing to do that in PHP you will need to do it manually; don't expect very good results.

Answer (score 1):

It is not feasible to distinguish ISO-8859-2 from Windows-1250, or any other single-byte encoding from any other encoding for that matter. `mb_detect_encoding` simply gives you the first encoding which is valid for the given string, and both are equally valid. "Detecting" encodings is by definition not possible with any amount of accuracy.

Comment: detecting encoding is important when you need to be sure that you are working with utf8. f.e. `iconv('Windows-1250', 'UTF-8', $str)` will give you different results than `iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', $html)`

Comment: Yes of course it will give you different results, just as getting wrong whether you're converting from a JPEG or PNG would. That still doesn't make any argument for why detection is possible. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: well if its possible to determinate that encoding conversion (in my example iconv Windows-1250 to UTF-8) returns wrong result, than based on this it should be possible to determinate proper encoding simply by trying different conversions and comparing results.

Comment: And how do you determine that the result is "wrong"? If it works technically without error (which it does from any 8-bit encoding, always), then the conversion is "correct". Only you as a human can figure out that it is apparently not. Or you'd have to apply really good heuristics, but that's still *guessing*.

Comment: correct. however "guessing" is "detection with `some` amount of accuracy". `enconv` does pretty good job in guessing, in fact its the best thing i could find.

Comment: You can make a very good guess based on country which is the source of character string. There are characters in one encoding that are used in some countries (like Poland or Czech Republic) when their counterparts in the other encoding (same hex code) are not used at all or very rarely. You can base on checking for existence of those characters or statistics (counting). For example if there are many xb1 and xb9 characters and it's Polish language text then it is probably Windows-1250. Those are "ą" and "ś" in that encoding which is often used. Those are "±" and "¶" in ISO-8859-2 - rarely used.