# mb_detect_encoding showing the same encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, hebrew, smpp

I have a weird problem , the following code :

```
$str = "נסיון" // <--- Hebrew chars
echo mb_detect_encoding ($str)."<br><br><br>";
$str = iconv (mb_detect_encoding($str),'UCS-2BE',$str);
echo mb_detect_encoding ($str)."<br><br><br>";
```

This will output :

UTF-8

UTF-8

This code is written in a file that's encoded (using Notepad++) in UTF-8 Without BOM, trying other encodings and didn't work.

I also tried converting the string using :

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str,'UCS-2BE');
```

But that didn't work either. Any insights?

Comment: What is the problem? To detect hebrew? How about `preg_match('/[\u0591-\u05F4]/', $sData);`

Comment: similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104340/mb-detect-encoding-doesnt-properly-working-with-windows-1250-cp1250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for mb_detect_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php), the function that establishes the order in which `mb_detect_encoding` tests different encodings:

> **mbstring** currently implements the following encoding detection filters. If there is an invalid byte sequence for the following encodings, encoding detection will fail.
>   UTF-8, UTF-7, ASCII, EUC-JP,SJIS, eucJP-win, SJIS-win, JIS, ISO-2022-JP
>
> For ISO-8859-*, mbstring always detects as ISO-8859-*.
>
> For UTF-16, UTF-32, UCS2 and UCS4, encoding detection will fail always.

So, you can't detect the encoding of the second string with the mb functions.